# How to set day and time reminder in Alexa using IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: datetime, reminders, alexa-voice-service, watson-assistant, alexa-slot

How to set reminder for day(Weekdays like Monday, Tuesday etc..) and time  in Alexa using IBM Watson Assistant? I am able to set date and time in IBM Watson Assistant using system entities like `@sys-date` and `@sys-time`.The context variables like `$day` and `$time` have been used to fetch and store the data. Challenge is that Alexa must fetch these values and set the reminder. Please help.

Specific points for which help required is:-

1. Setting the reminder for day and time in Alexa using IBM Watson assistant.
2. If reminder already exists then Alexa must be able to tell that. Still user intends to set another reminder, then Alexa must be able to set the fresh reminder.
3. If user intends to cancel the existing remidner. Then Alexa must be able to cancel that from Watson Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me I am not 100% sure what you are asking, so if I have this wrong forgive me. I take it from your posting that you have linked your Alexa instance back to an instance of Watson. ( Which is doable as developer, but Amazon at present will not allow this to become an Alexa Skill). If I understand right, you then wish to call back into Alexa and set up a reminder for a time and date. I have not tried this, (but may do so for my Alexa+Watson demos), but expect you would need to call out via a cloud function or AWS lambda to the [Alexa Reminders API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html) and then understand the response from this call out, and then return a message back to Alexa. 
Hope this answers your question.